# qTip2 hiding - combine unfocus, inactive and fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I'm using qTip2 for tooltips. I want to have this tooltip hiding behavior:
- toopltip hides when I click close button on title (`button: true`)
- tooltip hides when I click elsewhere on the page (`event: 'unfocus'`)
- tooltip hides when I don't interact with it for 3 seconds (`inactive: 3000`), but only if my mouse cursor is not on the tooltip  (`fixed: true`)

Hiding when close button is pressed is fine:

```
content: {
    title: {
        button: true
    }
}
```

Hiding when unfocus is also ok:

```
hide: { 
    event: 'unfocus'
}
```

Hiding when I don't interact with it is still no problem:

```
hide: { 
    event: 'unfocus',
    inactive: 3000
}
```

Now I can close the tooltip by clicking elsewhere on the page, or on close button, or by not moving mouse over the tooltip for 3 seconds. But when my mouse is on tooltip and it doesn't move for 3 seconds, the tooltip is also closed - this is undesirable.

For staying visible when mousing onto tooltip I can use this:

```
hide: { 
    fixed: true,
    delay: 3000
}
```

Now it closes when mouse is not on tooltip for 3 seconds. But not when I click elsewhere on the page. So let's combine `unfocus` and `fixed`:

```
hide: { 
    event: 'unfocus',
    fixed: true,
    delay: 3000
}
```

Now it will close when I click elsewhere on the page, but not after 3 seconds after leaving tooltip. So let's try adding `inactive`:

```
hide: { 
    event: 'unfocus',
    inactive: 3000,
    fixed: true,
    delay: 3000
}
```

Now it will close when I click elsewhere on the page, also after 3 seconds after leaving the tooltip, but also after 3 seconds of inactivity when I'm on the tooltip.

**How can I close tooltip when I click elsewhere on the page and after 3 seconds after leaving the tooltip, but not when I'm still on it?**

Comment: I'm brand new to qTip but all your attempts make me think it may not be possible. IF it's not, you might just have to configure it with everything but the "click elsewhere" part, then add your own $(document).click(...) handler that hides the tip if any element but the tip was clicked. Sorry I can't be of more help. I was looking for a answer to the same question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement and as [xr280xr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263832/xr280xr) mentions, the only solution I see is to implement the 'unfocus' part yourself. So you end up with your configuration being:

```
$el.qtip({
  content: {
    title: {
      button: true
    }
  },
  hide: {
    fixed: true,
    delay: 3000
  }
})
```

and then to implement the unfocus behaviour:

```
var api = $el.qtip('api');
$el.closest('html').on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
    api.hide(e)  
});
```

In a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pvanb/n04qL8jg/

Comment: Yes, it indeed looks like there is no non-hacky approach to this. Just a little problem with this code - if you have more elements with tooltip, on clicking elsewhere, only first tooltip in DOM is hidden. To hide all tooltips, just call `$el.qtip('hide');` in the mousedown function instead of using `api`.